# Java - cannot find symbol with two classes

Tags: java

I'm sure I've made a simple mistake here but I'm new to Java so looking for some help.

I have one class Cat with:

```
public class Cat {
    public double weight = 10.0;
}
```

and another class Heavy with:

```
public class Heavy {

    double gain = 10.0;
    public void total() {
        weight = weight + gain;
    }

}
```

When I try to compile Heavy.java I'm getting an error saying it cannot find the weight symbol (variable). Both files are in the same directory and the cat.java file has been compiled. What am I missing? Appreciate any advice!

Comment: There's no relationship between `Cat` and `Heavy`. `Heavy` needs an instance of `Cat` to get that field from.

Answer (score 2):

`weight` is a property of `Cat`
To be able to use it in Heavy class create an instance of cat like this
:

```
public class Heavy {

    double gain = 10.0;
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    public void total() {
        cat.weight = cat.weight + gain;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Say I wanted to create an instance of Cat in another class,

    public class CatMaker{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      Cat cat = new Cat();
     }
    }

How would I get the Heavy class to work with that?

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted :)  you would create an instance of Heavy inside the main class but since every instance of heavy has a Cat object you wouldn't need another cat object. If you need any more help mail me at jkananakis@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Heavy {
    double gain = 10.0;
    Cat aCat = new Cat();
    public void total() {
        aCat.weight = aCat.weight + gain;
    }

}
```

You might want something like this.  Instantiate the Cat object in the heavy class to use weight.